# EF4 connection problem

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

I'm working with Visual Studio 2010 express and MSSQL 2008 R2 express.
I've created model from DB tables.

Now I have problem with connection.
When I connected to DB with Management Studio, I can't run my project, I'm receiving exception with message "The underlying provider failed on Open".

Restart of SQL instance helps, than I can run my project and work with entities, but after that I can't connect to DB from Management Studio.

To connect successfully, I need to restart SQL server instance again.

Are there some ways to do that simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a little bit like your database might be set to [Single User Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345598.aspx), have you checked that?